# How to convert 2 bytes to one 16-bit number in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

So I have 2 bytes, for example: *13, 61*

I want to convert them into the 16-bit: 3389

Right now I'm using the function:

```
function IntPower(const N, k: integer): integer;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  Result:= (256 * N) + k;
end;
```

Are there any better way to do this on Delphi?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That method is fine. You could alternatively use shift operations:

```
Result := N shl 8 + k;
```

or

```
Result := N shl 8 or k;
```

Either works fine and you should pick whichever you prefer.

Comment: If N,K and result as defined as cardinal, compiler will in fact use SHL asm opcodes.

Comment: Not that it actually makes any discernible difference in the performance, integer multiplication is fast

Answer (score 5):

Two alternatives are

```
function CreateWord(const A, B: byte): word;
begin
  result := word(A) shl 8 or B;
end;
```

and

```
function CreateWord(const A, B: byte): word;
var
  WR: WordRec;
begin
  WR.Hi := A;
  WR.Lo := B;
  result := word(WR);
end;
```

Comment: See also MakeWord.

Comment: @OndrejKelle: That's exactly my `CreateWord`, except for the order of the arguments: my `CreateWord` matches OP's `IntPower`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is just fine.

If N,K and result as defined as cardinal, compiler will in fact use SHL asm opcodes, which in fact is not faster those days than * - MUL is a one-cycle op IIRC.

```
function IntPower(const N, k: cardinal): cardinal; inline;
begin
  Result:= (256 * N) + k;
end;
```

Here the main trick is to define `inline;` which will make the code much faster.